# Галерея при помощи Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal

Пытаюсь создать галерею при помощи Drupal 7. Создал тип материала "Галерея", добавил несколько модулей для удобства (Colorbox, multiupload и прочие). Теперь я хочу вывести конкретную галерею при помощи модуля Views, однако есть один нюанс: мне нужно сделать так, чтобы на странице были не все фотографии, а только одна и кнопки "Далее" и "Назад". Все фотографии добавляются в галерею при помощи поля "Изображение" с неограниченным количеством элементов.

В какую сторону копать?

Answer (score 1):

В сторону слайдера типа https://drupal.org/project/flexslider https://www.drupal.org/project/owlcarousel
В настройках views выбрать соответствующий формат вывода.